# Create a table structure in Greenplum

Tags: greenplum

I tried creating a table structure on Greenplum, with the following query:

```
create table dbname.check
(
    empid integer,
    empname character varying,
    salary bigint
)
distributed by empid
```

And the error I got is: `"cannot explain create table without an AS clause"`.

As far as I know the table structure create table queries are not supposed to have an AS clause. And even if I give an AS clause, it says that there is some error near the empid part.

Comment: Please post your error trace with question

Comment: I  have posted the error trace, and yes :) I am using postgresql. Green Plum.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the distributed column in ( )

So you should run:

```
create table dbname.check
(
    empid integer,
    empname character varying,
    salary bigint
)
distributed by (empid);
```